# Pulling value from properties file in different project in Java

Tags: java, file, properties

As the title suggests what I am trying is to pull a specific value from a properties file given the key. 
I did it and it works but the problem is that I am reading the file with an absolute path. So this won't work in a production environment.

The properties file is on another project, different from the one I am trying to read it.

```
LinkedList reasonOptionsList = new LinkedList(stopChecksPaymentsOrderFormPreview.getStopPaymentReasonCol());

            Properties pro = new Properties();
            String optReasonKey = ((EnumerationValue) reasonOptionsList.get(Integer.parseInt(stopChecksPaymentsOrderFormPreview.getStopPaymentReasonSelected())-1)).getMsgCode();
            String parsedReason = "";
            try{
                File file = new File("D:\\pbworkspace\\PBBogota\\bundles\\com\\ath\\psj\\web\\common\\messages\\pb\\Messages-Resources.properties");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
                pro.load(fis);

                parsedReason = pro.getProperty("stopPaymentOrder.".concat(optReasonKey));

            } catch(IOException e) {

                TraceUtility.catching(CLASS_NAME, "ERROR:", TRACE_TAG, e);
                logger.error("Ha ocurrido un error al consultar el archivo properties " + e);
            }
```

Is there a way to access the file without depending of an absolute path?, because this can change in another machine, or in a production environment.

It might not be located in D: anymore, all projects are inside PBBogota folder, the properties file belongs to bundles, while the invoking class belongs to pb

[image: project structure]

All projects are related to each other.

Note: I am working with Java 1.4 using a struts 1 framework.

Comment: the path that you pass in the constructor of new File should come from your local properties file and the local properties file on production should return the correct path for the production environment.

Comment: Hi Isaace  , sorry but how can I achieve that , can you point me a bit further ? Thanks